# How can I get all the documents from that firestore collection that have at least one object with a doctorId value equal to 1 in a collection x

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection with documents that follow the following model:

```
{
    "cardId": "12345678900",
    "phone": "123456789",
    "name": "Scott",
    "services": [
        {
            "name": "Estudios 3D para vías aéreas"
        },
        {
            "name": "Estudios 3D para ortodoncia"
        },
        {
            "name": "Estudios 3D para senos paranasales",
            "doctorId": "ASNDUasd981239nasd"
        },
        {
            "name": "Estudios 3D para implantes dentales",
            "pdfUrl": [],
            "imgUrl": [],
            "doctorId": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "Estudios 3D para vías aéreas",
            "imgUrl": [
                "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/cid-imagenes.appspot.com/o/patients%2Fimages%2Frc-upload-1678379057443-9?alt=media&token=b156f890-aa2a-49e8-aa73-52260124b279"
            ],
            "pdfUrl": [
                "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/cid-imagenes.appspot.com/o/patients%2Fdocuments%2Frc-upload-1678379057443-11?alt=media&token=c61378ba-413b-4e89-ba57-3a93e9f66a3f"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "lastname": "Castro",
    "birthdate": "Thu Mar 02 2023 15:43:23 GMT-0400 (hora estándar del Atlántico)",
    "gender": "M",
    "imgUrl": "",
    "type": "PATIENT",
    "email": "asdasd@asdasd.com",
    "referredById": 1
}
```

How can I get all the documents of that collection where at least one object inside the "services" array contains a doctorId property with the value of 1, the firebase library in react.

I tried using the method:

```
 query(ref, where('services', 'array-contains-any', { doctorId: 1 }));
```

But it doesn't work, because apart from the doctorId property, the object inside the "services" array has other properties, so it doesn't match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `array-contains` and `array-contains-any` operators compare the value you specify against each **entire** item in the array, and returns the document if there is an exact, complete match. You can't use them for partial matches.

The common solution is, as usual with NoSQL databases, to add additional data to allow the use-case. Here for example, you can add another top-level array field with all the doctor IDs:

```
doctorIds: [1]
```

And then you can query on that field with `array-contains`:

```
query(ref, where('doctorIds', 'array-contains', 1))
```